# Which sweep can fit this drip rail

Tags: bathroom, shower

I recently moved into a house and found one of the shower door leaked. There is no sweep under the door slab though the drip rail is there. I tried to find a matching sweep and checked all the sweeps I could find nearby, but none of them can slide into the slot. I would like to know which sweep can fit this drip rail.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That door doesn't need a sweep.

When the door is closed it is inside the bottom frame rail that  should contain the water.  That rail should be caulked, preferably along its *outside* edge and not the inside one so that water underneath it can drip into the shower.

The drip rail is to catch water rolling down the door while the door is open.  If installed properly it should be angled slightly downward from the handle side to the hinge side, and its hinge end should extend slightly over the bottom frame edge when the door is open up to 90 degrees.  The idea is that all the water rolling down the door will roll into the shower when you open it.  If you open the door further YMMV.  It needs a thin bead of caulk along the top of it, or perhaps just tightening.

If it's leaking, you need to run the shower and observe where the leak is coming from, bearing in mind the design aspects I've described.

Generally, frameless doors need floor sweeps.  Your door is capable of being installed framelessly.  If it was,the drip rail would function differently.  There is a channel you can see at the 10 o'clock position in your first photo.  There is a proprietary sweep that slides into that channel.  In a frameless installation, that sweep would contact the tile on the curb and keep water from running across the curb.  When the door is closed the drip rail would (if installed correctly) direct water into the shower tray so the sweep doesn't become inundated. With older doors if the proprietary sweep cannot be obtained you can sandwich a flat one between the door and the drip rail.  You don't need to do that.

Comment: The design of these doors and the idea of directing the flow of water is IMO over-engineered.  The user just needs to wait 3 or 4 seconds before opening the door and there won't be enough water left to create a drip-rail-river.  If she does not wait, (go ahead, burn me for that) you know her hair and body will transport a gallon or two of water onto the bathroom floor and there is nothing any shower door designer can do about it.